# how to access remote registry access between xp and vista using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, windows-vista, windows-xp, remote-access

I have to access remote connection from XP os to Vista os in vb.net
How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that help you:

```
    'Set the machine name
    Dim MachineName = "file-server"
    'This will hold the value of the query if successful
    Dim Value As String = Nothing
    'Open the remote HKLM hive
    Dim Reg = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, MachineName)
    'Open the key
    Dim Key = Reg.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion")
    'OpenSubKey returns Nothing on keys that don't exist so make sure we've got something
    If Key IsNot Nothing Then
        'Grab the value
        Value = Key.GetValue("CommonFilesDir")
    Else
        'Unable to open key, do something here
    End If
    'Very important, close the key and the hive
    Key.Close()
    Reg.Close()
    Trace.WriteLine(Value)
```